# HTML: Make window invisible?

Tags: html, window

How would I make a window invisible? I don't want to do `window.close()` because there still is some code to run post window closing so I'd like to just make it not visible. How would I do this?

Comment: You could make the viewport contents invisible...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in some browsers to [change the window size](http://www.cybertext.com.au/tips_HTML_window_size.htm), but I don't think it is possible to hide a window completely.